# does 'file' have a registered use in python? if so how do i use it with variables

Tags: python, hex

The first problem with this code is that it does not recognise the file dechex, which is my input for 'user', however unless it is obvious to you that this error is in this section of the code, I believe it to be due to a problem elsewhere.

My second problem with this code is that 'file' does not seem to be carrying out a function, although when I play around with the code it occassionally turns blue leading me to believe that in certain circumstances it does have a specific python purpose. Furthermore I don't understand how to name the file that is opened whilst also leaving the 'file' to carry out its function since you cannot rename file (since its a function) to file1 etc.

```
def dec2hex():
    user = raw_input("what's the file name?")
    file = open(user, 'r')
    num = file.read()
    num1 = int(num)
    num2 = hex(num1)
    file.close()
    file = open('Covertdec2hex2.txt','w')
    for x in num2:
        y = str(x)
        file.write(y)
    file.close()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your code works so what is the problem?

Comment: This doesn't recognise the filename, 'dechex' that I enter. I know the case entered is correct and it's in the right directory so does this code lead to answers I may be missing about why it's saying... IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dechex'.

Answer (score 0):

`file()` is obsolete; it has been deprecated by `open()`/`io.open()` in newer versions of Python, although `file` still exists as a type.

As for your filename issue, make sure that you're in/specifying the correct directory, and that the case matches if you're using a case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: would there be any other reason why filename isn't being recognised?even though I've entered it in the correct case and the file is in the same folder as the programme it still says...
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dechex'